# why when pass arguments on a sub vb6 i retrieve error?

Tags: vb6, arguments

i wrote this code:

```
Sub Insert_Pic_From_File2(PicPath As String, ByVal row As Integer, ByVal col As Integer)


Dim Pic As Picture, Sh As Shape, Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range.Cells(row, col)
Set Rng = Rng.MergeArea

With Rng
    Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=PicPath, linkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height)
    Sh.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
End With

Set Sh = Nothing
Set Rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

and I call it from this line:

```
Insert_Pic_From_File2 ("D:\Area Open\ok.png", y, col_result)
```

both y and col_result are integer.

When I press enter the program give this error (in italian)

> errore di compilazione: 
>   Previsto: =

i think in english:

> compilation error: 
>   needed: =

Why this?
if i delete the arguments y and col_result seems no problem, but without arguments.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use brackets round the parameters! They're only used if you use the redundant 'Call' statement or for Functions where a value is returned.

```
Insert_Pic_From_File2 "D:\Area Open\ok.png", y, col_result
```

should be fine